# AppLock feature on React-Native application

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, user-interface

I'm quite new to React-Native development and trying to implement AppLock feature in my application for both Android and IOS but not sure how to implement it.
It would be great if anyone can help me on this

Comment: what do you mean by app lock saikat? can you share your exact requirements so that we can help?

Comment: Pin/Pattern(i.e., set on the mobile) based applock that we generally get on financial apps for security purpose so that noone can open the app without it

Answer (score 1):

I believe first you will register a user and then ask for it's PIN to be set. And after that you will ask the user to enter pin while login , correct? 
If this is the flow please find the below points :

1.Then i would start by first during registration , ask the user to set a PIN and store it in database along with it.
2.Next when the user logins , first ask for the email and pin accordingly . you can use this article [react native pin](https://medium.com/@talut/react-native-pin-view-7969b211d885) to get along with . how to set the pin view correctly. Its a good library . or try some other libraries [rn-pinccode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-pin-code) 
3. When the user finishes pin code, you can call an api to cross verufy if thats the user ,  and then either show homepage or error screen.

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts.

Comment: No, I am looking for local mobile pin app lock